# How to add TextView to custom LinearLayout view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I created a custom view that extends LinearLayout. I'm adding them to the screen through a Service like this:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(view, mParams);
```

This works for a simple empty view with just a background color. But now I want to add TextViews, and I'm trying this:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tv.setText("Test text");
view.addView(tv);
```

However the TextViews aren't showing. What am I missing?

EDIT: I just noticed that the TextView is drawn if I remove this overrided method on the custom view:

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(getDesiredWidth(), getDesiredHeight());
    }
```

However, I need that line to properly set the size I want for the views.

Comment: call `super(...)` then

Comment: Calling super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) results on the TextView being displayed, but all other views don't appear.

Comment: what is getDesiredWidth() / getDesiredHeight() ? in pixels

Comment: When I create the views, I call the function setDesiredWidth() (or height) to set the size in pixels I want for the view. I need to resize them multiple times over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personsally go down the inflation route, as have had headaches in the past caused by programmatically adding views. Here's [a quick example of a custom view](https://github.com/noln/CustomViewDemos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/jammy/customviewdemos/Views/LinearLayoutWithTextBox.java) that's extended from LinearLayout, inflated from an XML layout file, with a public method for setting the value of the embedded textview.

The key bit is this:

```
private TextView embeddedTextView;

..

private void init() {

    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.linear_layout_with_textview_layout, this);

    embeddedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.embedded_text_view);

}

public void setEmbeddedTextViewText(String text) {

    embeddedTextView.setText(text);
}
```

I take this approach as you swap out different styled layouts in XML and use the same Custom View; proper code re-usability. Less work in the long-run.

Edit: Here's [a way of hiding the textview by default, or an empty string ""](https://github.com/noln/CustomViewDemos/commit/e358825eeba378266d1c18cc5efa7e97d93f9380#diff-64db4757e1fc3da8fc994cbc271b4c14).

Comment: But that way I'll add a TextView to every single view. I only want to add it for one of the views.

Comment: Then you could use **visbility:gone** on the TextView in the XML, and **setVisibility(VISIBLE)** if you set the text. When it's gone it doesn't show up anywhere in the View, and is ignored during layout. I've added that to the GitHub example.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to recreate the effect I wanted with this method!